# Cannot get Azure Storage Account File Share mapped on VM using PowerShell

Tags: azure, powershell, mapping, virtual-machine, drive

Trying to get an Azure fileshare (in 'ResourceGroup1') mapped to a drive letter using powershell: `New-PSDrive –Name 'Z' –PSProvider FileSystem –Root '\\sa1.file.core.windows.net\solutionfiles'`.

I keep getting error "*New-PSDrive : The specified drive root "\\sa1.file.core.windows.net\solutionfiles" either does not exist, or it is not a folder*". But is exists!

'New-PSDrive' gives an unwanted pop-up when adding a '-Credential' parameter even if I provide a PSCredential object. When I enter SAName and SAKey manually then the mapping works. However, for an automation I cannot use a pop-up. What to do?

Answer (score 0):

Just used the following feeling lucky:

```
Invoke-Expression -Command "cmdkey /add:SA1.file.core.windows.net /user:Azure\sbl266aucy3e2sa01 /pass:SAKey
```

No idea yet what this is doing ('cmdkey'???), but it hands over the credentials somehow to ??? so that the original cmdlet to map a drive now works:

```
New-PSDrive -Name Z -PSProvider FileSystem -Root "\\sbl266aucy3e2sa01.file.core.windows.net\solutionfiles"
```

//

Comment: Just googled that "'cmdkey' is a built-in Windows tool that can cache domain user credentials for use on specific target machines." Interesting that they call a command to 'cache domain user credentials' "cmdkey". Another cool name would have been "michaeljackson", wouldn't it?